# How to cancel a call with XCTest for iOS 14

Tags: swift, xcode, testing, xctest, ios14

Hi I'm writing some XCTest in Swift for iOS 14.

Back in iOS 13 the springboard handled the call screen and you could end a call with

```
let app = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")

app.buttons["End call"].firstMatch.tap()
```

However the springboard does not seem to contain the end call button for iOS 14! So how do you end a call in iOS 14?

Comment: hmm is there any button closing or ending the call ( i think it should be ) ?

Comment: Yes there is, but i can't access it with the springboard application or my own application. it exists in some other application.

Comment: i see then we should catch the like "end call" with accessibility identifier tool in xcode. Do you know how it is or should i drop an answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to inspect what application is displayed by reading Apple's Console application output. (Search for FBApplication)

Probably, you need to interact with the Phone application instead of Springboard

Bundle identifiers of iOS apps: https://github.com/rzakhar/XCTApps/blob/master/Sources/XCTApps/iOS.swift